# Forward Iterator on a Stack

Tags: c++, iterator

i have to implement a forward iterator on a stack based on arrays. I can't use std::vectors or anything, i just need that. My development of this program stopped when i begun with forward iterator, and in particular with the operators.

I have a method that takes a generic sequence, and from that, given an offset, creates a stack:

```
template <typename IterT>       
  stack(IterT begin, IterT end) : _stack(0), _size(0), _capacity(0) {
    try {       
        for(; begin!=end; ++begin) {
            push(static_cast<T>(*begin));       
        }
    }
    catch(...) {
        clear();   //my method to destroy the stack 
        throw;
    }
}
```

In my main i do the following:

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
stack<int> sint(a, a+5);
cout << sint << endl;
```

But when the code runs the stack is created but not printed. Can somebody help me? And also give me other helps(on code indentation, improvements, etc...) Thank you, I will post the iterator code forward.

```
 class const_iterator {
    const T* data;
    unsigned int index;
public:
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef T                         value_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t                 difference_type;
    typedef const T*                  pointer;
    typedef const T&                  reference;

    const_iterator() : data(0){}

    const_iterator(const T* arr) : data(arr) {}

    const_iterator(const const_iterator &other) 
        : data(other.data){ }

    const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator &other) {
        data = other.data;
        return *this;
    }

    ~const_iterator() {
        data = 0;
    }

    reference operator*() const {
        return *data;
    }

    pointer operator->() const {
        return &(data);
    }

    const_iterator operator++(int) {
        const_iterator tmp(*this);
        ++*this;
        return tmp;
    }

    const_iterator& operator++() {
        ++data;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return data[index] == other.data[index];
    }

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return data[index] != other.data[index] ;
    }


private:

    friend class stack; 

    const_iterator(unsigned int ind) :
        index(ind){}

}; // class const_iterator

const_iterator begin() const {
    cout << "begin" << _stack[_size-1] << endl;
    return const_iterator(_stack[_size-1]);
}

const_iterator end() const {
    cout << "end" << _stack[0] << endl;
    return const_iterator(_stack[0]);
}
```

Last but not least i redefined the << operator to fit the iterator:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const stack<T> &st) {
typename stack<T>::const_iterator i, ie;
for(i = st.begin(), ie = st.end(); i!=ie; ++i){
    os << *i << std::endl;
}
return os;
}
```

The code for the stack is the following (I omitted something for readability).

```
stack()
    : _capacity(0), _size(0), _stack(0){}
void push (const T &value){
    if (_size == _capacity){    //raddoppio la dimensione 
        if(_capacity == 0)
            ++_capacity;
        _capacity *= 2;
        T* tmp = new T[_capacity];
        copy_n(_stack, _size, tmp);
        swap(_stack, tmp);
        delete[] tmp;
    }
    _stack[_size] = value;
    ++_size;
}

void pop(){
    T _tmp;
    if(!is_empty()){
        _tmp = _stack[_size-1];
        --_size;
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to strip down the irrelevant parts to make it less code and add what is missing so we can reproduce it (see also [mcve]). btw how is your `clear` in the stack constructor supposed to "destroy the stack"?

Comment: Note that your iterator class will *not* be used for `stack<int> sint(a, a+5);`. The `IterT` type will be deduced as `int*`.

Comment: I also recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: btw2 your `operator==` is not correct. You consider two different iterators pointing to different positions as equal when the element at that position is the same, thats not how equality of iterators usually works

Comment: `operator->()`, though not used, should return `data` itself, not its address, and you don't need `index` in the iterator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it’s not used in the construction of the stack but in the printing, as it uses the << operator

Comment: @user463035818 yeah I got it and I knew that’s wrong, but I can not figure out how to do it. I have to compare the content of the arrays pointed by indexes but I can’t do it.

Comment: @Evg why shouldn’t I use index?

Comment: Isn't `data` already plays a role of `index`? Your `operator++` increments `data`, not `index`. Could you describe in plain words what your iterator is supposed to do? Shouldn't it be equivalent to a plain pointer (like `std::vector<T>::iterator`)?

Comment: @Evg yes, it should just be like a pointer

Comment: Then you don't need `index`, and `data` should be your pointer.

Comment: And another clarification is needed: do you want to create a reverse iterator, such that `operator++` goes from the top of the stack to its bottom?

Comment: @Evg exactly need that

Comment: See my answer. If anything is not clear, make a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an iterator that looks like a pointer, you don't need `index`, because `data` plays its role. Comparison operator should compare `data`s, not values:

```
bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const {
    return data == other.data;
}
```

If you want to create a [reverse iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator), it is slightly more complex. First, `operator++` should decrement `data`. Second, dereference operator should return not `*data`, but `*(data - 1)`. Third, `data` in the `begin()` iterator should point to `stack[size]`, and `data` in the `end()` iterator should point to `stack[0]`. You don't need a destructor in any case.

Comment: And do you think the other operators are right? I may want to try the first option, then if the time is enough i will try and swap to the reverse iterator @Evg

Comment: @man_o_war, `operator!=` should be corrected, too. And `operator->()` should return `data` itself. The rest look fine. If you implement a direct iterator with `operator++` incrementing `data`, `data` in the `begin` should point before `data` in the `end` iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the previous advices and here's the edited result, still i can't figure out how to properly use the constructor in the private section

```
class const_iterator {
    const T *data;
public:
    /* ITERATOR TRAITS HERE */

    const_iterator() : data(0){}

    const_iterator(const T* arr) : data(arr) {}

    const_iterator(const const_iterator &other) 
        : data(other.data){ }

    const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator &other) {
        data = other.data;
        return *this;
    }

    ~const_iterator() {
        data = 0;
    }

    reference operator*() const {
        return *data;
    }

    pointer operator->() const {
        return &(data);
    }

    const_iterator operator++(int) {
        const_iterator tmp(*this);
        ++*this;
        return tmp;
    }

    const_iterator& operator++() {
        ++data;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return data == other.data;
    }

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return data != other.data;
    }

private:
    friend class stack; 

    const_iterator(const T *d) {
        data = d;
    }

}; // classe const_iterator

const_iterator begin() const {
    return const_iterator(_stack[_size-1]);
}

const_iterator end() const {
    return const_iterator(_stack[0]);
}
```

Comment: 1) Your destructor does nothing useful. 2) `operator->()` should return `data`. 3) The whole `private` section is redundant. 4) `begin()` should be constructed with `stack[0]`, `end()` - with `stack[size]` (keep in mind, the `[begin, end)` range is half-open).

Comment: Yes, thanks, but when i try to compile it statest that i try to convert an `int` to a `const int*` on my begin and end methods, and i can't stand how i should do that

Comment: Use `&_stack[0]` and `&_stack[_size]`.

Comment: dude, I just think i really love you <3